# query 2 database from different servers without using federate

Tags: mysql

I was looking into how to do a query between 2 database on different servers.
I am trying to select another database from another server and insert into my local server.

I am trying to migrate tables with different schema so I have to build its design to be identical to the new design before inserting.

Any suggestions? I was checking Federated but it required me to change the database engine on the remote server w/c I didn't want to do.

So, is this possible? If not, then I'll just use python to migrate and connect between 2 servers.

Comment: If it's not a huge database dump it from server1. Import into a separate staging database on a server2. Now do all the transformations you want with your data  on server2.

Comment: It's huge and it requires to be done in that way because the remote server is live.